# Disable a class in a URL

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress video blog which I have designed so that when viewing the homepage, the content area is left-aligned with a right-aligned sidebar. If the visitor clicks on to the page of a specific blog post, the sidebar is moved down below the content area and the content area (and the video therein) becomes much larger.

In the header.php, I have a line that reads:

```
<body<?php if ( is_single() ) {
echo ' class="widescreen" '; } ?>>
```

And in the style.css

```
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 660px;
}

.widescreen #content {
    width: 940px;
}
```

I wish to, if possible, give my visitors the chance to view the single post page with the smaller video size available on the homepage, if for some reason they prefer it that size, and do not wish to search for that particular post in the archive.

I was wondering if it is possible to provide a link to an alternate version of the page with the 'widescreen' class disabled. Something in the realm of: 'website.com/post&class:widescreen=false', although obviously not that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript for that:

```
document.getElementById("content").className = "";
```

You can see a live demo here: http://jsbin.com/yiducicu/1/

The trick is call a function in a hyperlink that switch between removing the class and putting back on.

```
function setWidescreen(){
   if (document.getElementById("content").className == ""){
     document.getElementById("content").className = "widescreen";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("content").className = "";
   }
}
```

Comment: Javascript is one of my weak points. How would I implement that into a hyperlink?

Comment: I made you an example here: http://jsbin.com/yiducicu/1/ I'm editing my answer now.

Comment: Okay, I've implemented this code and it's behaving very strangely. #content isn't the only element affected by the widescreen class, and when I press the button, the Javascript changes the widescreen class for every element EXCEPT #content. Another anomoly is that the code works on pages where the widescreen class is intially disabled, such as my homepage. The button turns it both on and off. Yet on pages where the class is initially active, it does neither.